# Initialization error when creating an object

Tags: dart

When I compile the following code:

```dart
class Student {
  int id;

  Student() {
    this.id = 12345;
  }
}

void main() {
  var student1 = new Student();
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Field 'id' should be initialized because its type 'int' doesn't
> allow null.

But why do I get this error? I did initialize `id` in the constructor!

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, the creation of objects are split into two phases:

- Initialization of all values.
- Execution of constructor body.

So when you are running code inside the constructor body (between the `{...}` in the constructor definition) then all class defined variables must have been provided a default value that is valid for the type of variable.

In your case, the variable is typed `int` but are not provided a default value. In Dart, all variable will by default be set to `null` in case of no other value provided. But since `int` is a non-nullable type it does not allow `null` to be a value and the compiler are therefore giving you the error.

The solution are to provide a value before the constructor is running. You can do that like this:

```dart
class Student {
  int id;

  Student() : id = 12345;
}
```

Or:

```dart
class Student {
  int id = 12345;

  Student(); // The constructor can in theory just be removed here
}
```

In case you cannot define a value as part of the initialization phase, you can (but should be prevented if possible) mark the variable as `late` which makes it so you promise, the Dart compiler, that you are going to provide a value for the variable before the first time you are trying to read from that variable:

```dart
class Student {
  late int id;

  Student() {
    this.id = 12345;
  }
}
```

In case you are trying to read from `id` before it have been provided a value, the program will crash with a `LateInitializationError` at runtime.

And at last, you can set the type to be a nullable type, like `int?`, to allow the variable to have a default value of `null`. But doing so will require you to check for `null` when you are trying to do something with the value in a context where `null` is not allowed:

```dart
class Student {
  int? id;

  Student() {
    this.id = 12345;
  }
}
```